# Looking for clojure-csv library example that uses write-csv

Tags: clojure

I am looking for a clojure-csv library example that uses write-csv. Specifically, how are the arguments formed? I cannot figure out why I am getting the following error below.

Here is my code example with error:

```
(def x [1 2 3 4]) 

(write-csv (spit "test.tmp" x) :end-of-line "\n")    

ArityException Wrong number of args (3) passed to:
      core$write-csv  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:437)
```

Thank You.

Comment: One problem is, that `spit` returns `nil`, so that's what you're passing as first argument. And `write-csv` is documented as expecting a sequence of sequences of strings, which `x` isn't. What do you get from `(write-csv [["1" "2" "3" "4"]])` and from  `(write-csv [["1" "2" "3" "4"]] :end-of-line "\n")`? Still the error is odd...

Comment: Unless you are fetching from master, this is expected. I don't see any release tags that support adding options to `write-csv`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** Misread your question and didn't realize you were asking about using the library clojure-csv. Going to leave this up in case it helps anyone else using clojure.data.csv.

If you are using leiningen put the following in your project.clj file.

```
(defproject so "example"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]
                 [org.clojure/data.csv "0.1.2"]])
```

Example code of creating a function which takes a filename and the data to write to a csv.

```
(ns so.core
  (:require [clojure.data.csv :as csv]
            [clojure.java.io :as io]))

(defn csv [filename data]
  (with-open [f (io/writer filename)]
    (csv/write-csv f data)))
```

Using `csv` from the repl.

```
so.core> (csv "example.csv" [["stack" 1]
                         ["example" 40]])
```

And here is what example.csv looks like.

```
$ cat example.csv 
stack,1
example,40
```

Hopefully this helps out.

Comment: Many thanks. I had no need for this until today, and it works swell.